# grub2win isoboot CloneZilla LiveCD unable to find a medium containing a live file system

Tags: boot, grub2, initramfs, livecd, clonezilla

Help, please. I've got:

1. Win10 Pro. With legacy bios bootloader.
2. Installed grub2win bootloader. Added menu entry isoboot CloneZilla LiveCD. iso-file situated on local disk with NTFS file system.
3. Menu isboot params:

```
set isopath='/clonezilla-live-2.6.6-15-amd64.iso'
set kernelpath='/live/vmlinuz'
set initrdpath='/live/initrd.img'
set bootparms='boot=live iso-scan/filename='$isopath' noprompt noeject ---'
```

4. Reboot. Picking up isboot menu entry and got an error:

```
unable to find a medium containing a live file system
```

In console the last successful line:
`fuse: init (API version 7.31)` then boot process stops in `initramfs` cli.

How i tried to fix?

1. Used other iso (debian mini, ubuntu mini) - works perfect. I supposed there is no problems with ntfs, where iso is situated.
2. Changed `bootparms`. Took from grub2 on livecd `/boot/grub.cfg`. Full list:

```
boot=live union=overlay username=user config components quiet noswap edd=on nomodeset enforcing=0 locales= keyboard-layouts= ocs_live_run="ocs-live-general" ocs_live_extra_param="" ocs_live_batch="no" vga=788 ip= net.ifnames=0  splash i915.blacklist=yes radeonhd.blacklist=yes nouveau.blacklist=yes vmwgfx.enable_fbdev=1
```

I tried to add one by one. But the error is the same. No differences.

How can I fix it and boot to LiveCD? Any ideas appreciated!